# how to set background color of combobox when index position of already selected item changes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I need to highlight combobox background, if any selection have been changed to already selected item of combo box and to reset background when selected back to its original Index/Selection ?

need only XAML based solution only

Comment: got no clue yet, still searching

Comment: Use `EventTrigger` in your `ComboBox`